# Azure | ADF | Change value from dictionary saved in parameter (ADF)

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have a global parameter in Azure Data Factory of object type.

The value could be something like

```
{"values":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

I know that you can set the value of a global parameter using pipeline expressions.

Is there a way to change the value of one of the keys of the object and save changes back to the parameter using a pipeline?

Comment: You can edit the global parameter and save. Look at this [img](https://i.imgur.com/42hp0dO.png)

Answer (score 0):

- A global parameter is created with

> Name: globalParameter
> Type: Object
> Value: {"values":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}

[image]

- Here, I tried to change the value of key1 to **value3**.
- In global parameters, **Edit all** is clicked.

[image]

- Value of key1 is changed and then saved.
  [image]
- By this way, values of the global parameter can be changed.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. What I want is to change the value programmatically within the pipeline.

Comment: It is not possible to change using ADF pipeline